# How to yank between files?

Tags: vim, yank

For example, when I yank some text from vim, then `:wq`, and open a new file. When I try to paste the text I just yanked, it doesn't work. So how to yank text between files?

Comment: I'm confused what's the problem?

Answer (score 13):

use `"+y` to send the yanked text to the clipboard, and `"+p` to paste it into the new file.

So if I have a file named **A** that contains `abcdef` and I *(in visual mode)* select `def` and then press `"+y` while in *normal* mode.  I have just copied `def` to the system clipboard.  Now I can open up a file named **B** and *(while in normal mode)* press `"+p` the text `def` will be pasted into file **B**.

Comment: Note that this only works when your copy of Vim is compiled with clipboard support.  Not sure? Try `:echo has('clipboard')`.  If `1`, you have it.  If `0`, you don't.

Comment: @Riley, you can also find out with `:version` and then see if `clipboard` has a little plus sign (`+`) in front of it.

Comment: definitely, but I find that it's a bit of a pain to try to read through that feature list.  Your call though!

Comment: when I go to normal mode I lose the highlighted text.

Comment: fyi on ubuntu you need to now (20.0) install vim-gtk to get the clipboard option

Answer (score 9):

Don't quit the editor after writing with `:wq`

Instead, just write the file with `:w` and then edit the new file with `:e file`.  Or Edit both at the same time by splitting with `:sp file` and `^W` to switch between the screens.

Answer (score 3):

- if you have X11/windows, you could use `"+y` or `"*y` to yank. and same register to paste.
- don't do `:wq` and then `vim newfile`. do `:e newfile` in same vim. then you could yank and paste between buffers. just press `y` and `p`
- if you work on tty or via ssh, and don't want to do (2) either, you could save yanked part to a file, in newfile read the file.

I recommend the (2) option.

Comment: What's the difference between `:e` and `:o`?

Comment: @OneZero did you try `:h` them or test the both?  open your vim, then press `Q`, now you type `e` or `o`, you see difference.

Answer (score 2):

Vim has the capability of viewing multiple files at once. Use the `:sp *file_name*` "split" or `:vs *file_name*` "vertical split" commands to view another file in the same terminal.

Navigation between open file windows is simple: press `Control_key + w`and then either 'h', 'j', 'k', or 'l' to move the cursor to the file window to either the left, the bottom, the top, or the right of the current window. Simply 'yank' the text that you mean to copy in one terminal window, move to the terminal window containing the file that you mean to copy into as described above, and 'put' the text at the cursor location as usual.

By the way, you may use the `:wqa` command to close all open terminal windows and write changes made to the open files to the disk.